# DBF tables in Foxpo could get corrupt when reindex? (Without outage or crash)

Tags: dbf, visual-foxpro

We have a Foxpro exe application that is shared in a server and about 20 users run it.
One colleague told me that if those dbf tables need to be reindexed, he should tell everybody to leave the exe application. If reindex process starts and some user is still running that application, then dbf tables will get corrupted.

That was intriguing me. Is that possible? Always thought that when reindexing a Foxprox DBF table, the process itself open table in exclusive mode and if table is already open in shared mode, it just did nothing to that table. Similar with PAK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I agree that FoxPro tables can get corrupt, it is impossible from the situation you described. To reindex, you must have exclusive use of the table. Either you get a file lock or you don't:

1. If someone is in the application and has a table open, then your
   reindex routine will either fail or it will not be able to reindex
   the files that are open. Your notion about doing "nothing to that table" is true if the programming to reindex tables handles errors when trying to lock tables that are already open.
2. If your reindex routine is running and
   someone happens to be in the application or tries to run the
   application, they will most likely get errors and/or crash the app
   because they will not be able to open the tables (in shared mode).

[Here is a list of most likely culprits of table corruption](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264867). There is mention of file locking problems, but that has to do with tables that include memo fields. These tables actually consist of 2 files (the DBF [table] and the FPT [memo]). I've had apps run for years without any corruption whatsoever.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer, and should have been the one accepted as such. It's based on actual fact, and backed by documentation instead of just speculation and opinion.

Comment: I agree, with this answer. The first answer is incorrect. In VFP, you have to have exclusive use of the table(s) in order to reindex. I've been developing VFP applications in all versions of VFP since the late 90s and have never had a corrupt table. And these are large scale apps.

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect answer.  OP, feel free to remove mine.  Speculation?  "When the table is reindexing, its regenerating the structural .cdx file along with any .idx files. Accessing or attempting to access the data could corrupt the table, very easily, might i add." is actually a true statement.

Comment: @Kris: No, it's not "actually a true statement". In order to reindex, FoxPro requires that the database be opened in exclusive mode, meaning it's locked both at the database driver and the operating system levels. Nothing else **can** access the table and corrupt data, which I explained in my comment to your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a valid memo file over the corrupt memo file to access the database again.

NOTE: The original memo field information will be lost unless the valid memo file was an exact backup of the corrupt file. All memo field backup files have an extension of .TBK.

The corrupt memo file will have an .FPT extension, such as OLD.FPT. In the following example, assume NEW.FPT is a valid memo file. To bypass the error message and access the database again, type the following command at the MS- DOS command prompt:

copy new.fpt old.fpt

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to turn off all computers including the server.  Then reboot the sever (assuming the DBF file is on the server) and run a reindex.